# Date-fns is being received as null value on the backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, date-fns

- Frontend: React
- Backend: SpringBoot
- Date format on the BE: *2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z*

I've tried to use the **date-fns** to send the correct format from the FE to the BE application, ut even following the documentation, the BE is receiving null.

```
Salvar = async () => {
    const {update} = this.state;
     const {dtInclusao} = this.state.compra.dtInclusao
     var result = parse(
     dtInclusao,
     "dd/mm/yyyy",
     new Date()
     )
      const response = await api.post('SolicCompra/compra', 
      {...this.state.compra, dtInclusao: result},  {'Content-type': 
      'application/json'});
```

The expected format is **dd/MM/yyyy**.

Comment: Please see: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) Use [edit] option to correct it or move it to proper StackExchange site mentioned in linked post.

Comment: Proper StackExchange site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(result)` before making the API request?

Comment: @JakeLuby yes! "Invalid Date"

Comment: I posted an answer below that I think should help.  Assuming your `dtInclusao` variable is a valid date string

Comment: Acho que sei onde eu errei, eu estava mandando const {dtInclusao} sendo que era sem as chaves, apenas const dtInclusao. 
Consegui cadastrar, mas quando clico para editar, vem no campo dtInclusao populado naquele outro formato que eu não quero: 2019-11-11T03:00:00.000+0000 ...

Comment: JSON is send to the backend as a String, like when you use JSON.stringify. that converts Dates into Strings, example: `2020-08-28T03:20:00.000+00:00` to `"2020-08-28T03:20:00.000+00:00"`, to solve it you just need to pass that String as an argument for new Date: `new Date("2020-08-28T03:20:00.000+00:00")`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some date-fns helpers I use on a regular basis:

```
export const parseDate = dateString => {
  return Date.parse(dateString.replace(/-/g, '/').replace('T', ' '))
}

export const formatDate = date => {
  return format(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
}
```

The first will parse date and timestamps into a `Date` object.  The second will take that date object and format it back to a string in the format you want.

Using these helper functions you can update your code to:

```
var result = formatDate(parseDate(dtInclusao))
```